# Why ionic cordova + fileTransfer returns 403 error when requested on google-drive

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, google-drive-api, http-status-code-403

I got an error when working with ionic cordova and gdrive. I am trying to get or download data from the cloud. The first few times everything works correctly, but after a few tries I get a 403 error. How can I fix this? (For example, I use cordova fileTransfer)

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.